# I read that 'rlike' is case insensitive in MySQL -- but it's not working like that for me

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, case-insensitive

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html, "REGEXP is not case sensitive, except when used with binary strings."  Well... I'm not using binary strings -- at least, as I understand them (and as they imply in their examples).  And yet...

```
mysql> select hostname from hosts where hostname regexp '17503a';
+-----------------------+
| hostname              |
+-----------------------+
| ccdn-ats-tk-17503a-01 |
| ccdn-ats-tk-17503a-02 |
+-----------------------+
2 rows in set (0.08 sec)

mysql> select hostname from hosts where hostname regexp '17503A';
+-------------------+
| hostname          |
+-------------------+
| ccdn-ss-17503A-01 |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-02 |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-03 |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-04 |
+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.08 sec)
```

That looks an awful lot like a case-sensitive search to me.  Any help?

As requested, here's the (abbreviated) schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `hosts` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hostname` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','decommissioned','offlined','deploy','down') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT 'deploy',
  `onteak` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nagios` enum('monitored','unmonitored') COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `serial_num` (`serial_num`),
  UNIQUE KEY `ip` (`ip`),
  UNIQUE KEY `hostname` (`hostname`),
  KEY `fk_loc` (`loc`),
  KEY `hostname_idx` (`hostname`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=43075 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

And I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the whole "collate=utf8_bin" is what's biting me.  Thanks!

Update: spencer7593 nailed a work-around -- very excited:

```
mysql> SELECT hostname FROM hosts WHERE hostname REGEXP '17503a' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
+-----------------------+
| hostname              |
+-----------------------+
| ccdn-ats-tk-17503a-01 |
| ccdn-ats-tk-17503a-02 |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-01     |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-02     |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-03     |
| ccdn-ss-17503A-04     |
+-----------------------+
6 rows in set (0.03 sec)
```

Comment: The collation might be case sensitive,do a SHOW CREATE TABLE hosts and check the collation

Comment: please post the schema for the `hosts` table

Answer (score 1):

Yep. The utf8_bin is a *binary* collation, and that is effectively case sensitive.

You could try specifying a case insensitive collation; I've done this with equality comparisons, but never tried it with REGEXP ...

```
SELECT hostname FROM hosts WHERE hostname REGEXP '17503a' COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
                                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
SELECT hostname FROM hosts WHERE hostname COLLATE utf8_general_ci REGEXP '17503a' ;
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

(Give one of those a whirl and see how big a smoke ball it makes.)

Comment: Sir, I thank you.  That worked like an absolute charm: